# What is a sufficient condition for summability of formel power series?

Tags: limits-and-convergence, power-series, complex-manifolds, laplace-transform, divergent-series

There are several kind of summability , i accrossed differents conditions for applying for example Borel summation or laplace transform which let me mixed and confused  , really i don't know if i have for example a complex valued function f or real valued presented as a formel series function to judge if it is summable or no , then my question here is :

> > **Question**: What is a  sufficient condition for summability of formel power series ?

Comment: Trivial answer: absolute convergence is a sufficient condition for summability.

Comment: what about if it is also  absolute divergent ?

Answer (score 3):

*Note* The following strictly speaking does not answer the question but it may answer what the OP *meant*, i.e., under which conditions a formal power series defines a function.

**Edit** My memory didn't fail me. The following is taken almost verbatim from Reed and Simon Vol 4 see [here](https://books.google.it/books?id=dnjNCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA43&lpg=PA43&dq=strong+asymptotic+series&source=bl&ots=nyxqxv4tsQ&sig=bKz17Snu06FKc7gqwOOUIWzARrc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjnqobmtLTYAhUINxQKHTMBCuEQ6AEIODAC#v=onepage&q=strong%20asymptotic%20series&f=false)

> **Definition 1**  we say that a function $E\left(\lambda\right),$
>        analytic in a sectorial region 
>    $$\Omega=\left\{ z|0<\left|z\right|<B;\left|\textrm{arg}\left(z\right)\right|<\pi/2+\epsilon\right\} ,
>  $$
>    obeys a *strong asymptotic condition* and has $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}\lambda^{n}$
>   as *strong asymptotic series* (SAS) if there are positive constant $C$ and $\sigma$
>   such that
>   $$
> \left|E\left(\lambda\right)-\sum_{n=0}^{N}a_{n}\lambda^{n}\right|<C\sigma^{N+1}\left(N+1\right)!\left|\lambda\right|^{N+1}
> $$
>    for all $N$ and all $\lambda\in\Omega$.

Given the above one has:

> **Theorem** A SAS defines a function in the sense that if two analitic functions $f,g$ have the same SAS then $f=g$.

*Remark:* Informally the coefficients must not grow too fast. In fact SAS implies  $\left|a_{n}\right|\le C \sigma^{n}n!$.

There are
series associated with simple examples for which $a_n$ behaves like $(kn)!$ with
$k > 1$. Thus, a strong asymptotic condition cannot hold in such cases. However with a simple modification even this case may be treated. This suggests that we define:

> **Definition 2**  we say that a function $E\left(\lambda\right),$
>        analytic in a sectorial region $$\Omega=\left\{ z|0<\left|z\right|<B;\left|\textrm{arg}\left(z\right)\right|<\pi/2+\epsilon\right\} ,$$
>   obeys a **modified strong asymptotic condition of order $k$** and has $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}\lambda^{n}$
>   as an **order $k$ strong asymptotic series**  if there are positive constant $C$ and $\sigma$
>   such that
>   $$
> \left|E\left(\lambda\right)-\sum_{n=0}^{N}a_{n}\lambda^{n}\right|<C\sigma^{N+1}\left [ k(N+1) \right]!\left|\lambda\right|^{N+1}
> $$
>    for all $N$ and all $\lambda\in\Omega$.

The above result extends to this case too. Namely

> **Theorem 2** If $f,g$ both have $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}\lambda^{n}$ as order $k$ strong asymptotic series, then $f=g$.

Comment: @Icv , if you have the radius of convergence is 0 , can you say the coefficients not grow fast ?

Comment: The definition seems needlessly complicated. For any positive $C$ and $\sigma$, there is a $C'$ so that $C\sigma^{N+1}\le C'(N+1)!$ for all $N$, so there's no need to have $\sigma$ in the definition. Ditto in your remark, the $k$ seems superfluous. Also, it would be easier to read if you displayed the definition of $\Omega$.

Comment: @JoeSilverman I agree. The reason is that such condition admits a generalization, which then looks more understandable.

Comment: @JackWonder I'm not sure I understand. Yes of course. The point is to be able to define a function even for some series whose radius of convergence is zero.

Comment: @JoeSilverman I added the generalization and found the reference. Basically these are applications/extensions of Carleman's theorem.